# iPhone push notification not working

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notification in iPhone.
I have already done it some months ago. That time, after installing the aps_development.cer certificate, I exported it from keychain as a .p12 file. Then created the .pem certificate with that .p12 file using terminal. This .pem certificate is used in server for push implementation.

But now, when I am checking tutorials for the push implementation, I am seeing that both the .cer and .p12 file have to be converted into .pem. Then both .pem have to be combined using terminal.

Please confirm the steps needed.

Comment: just check this tutorial also may be you will got your answer.. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this  [Link](http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/), i always use this links Commands for creating **PEM** file.Please let me know if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use .p12 file only at server side for APN

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in this tutorial "http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12", it says both the .cer and .p12 have to be converted. Please check.